# Using an existing expression/func to build out another expression/func

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, entity-framework-core, expression

I want to be able to use a generic method to select a property and pass that into the [Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-2.2) method.

```
private List<TModel> _models;

public bool Any<TModel, TProperty>(
  Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> propertySelector,
  TModel model)
{
  // ....
}
// OR
public bool Any<TModel, TProperty>(
  Func<TModel, TProperty> propertySelector,
  TModel model)
{
  // ....
}
```

I'm not sure how to take the `propertySelector` and use it with the `Any()` on a `List<TModel>`.

This is close, but I'm missing something:

```
_models.Any(m => propertySelector(m) == propertySeletor(model));
```

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TProperty' and 'TProperty'

What am I missing here?

The question is more of a contrived example, as the Expression will ultimately be consumed by [entity-framework-core](/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core) to build a query.

Comment: I'm guessing that `propertySelector(model)` isn't going to change during the iteration over `_models`. Could you do something that takes `m => propertySelector(m)` as an expression, and the result of `propertySelector(model)` as a TProperty? I'm thinking about combining the former expression with the latter as a `ConstantExpression` in an `EqualExpression` and creating a delegate from that.

Comment: You are correct on `propertySelector(model)`.  I'm not quite sure what your second sentence fully means, nor why the result of a `TProperty` would solve the problem (especially based on the exception message).

Comment: I think I did too.  Instead of making TProperty generic, it seems to work if I specify the type (string, int, long).  I think this is one of those cases where I have to build out one for each value type.

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to consider my answer?

Comment: @madreflection I still need to, but I'm currently working on something else.  When I get a change to jump back on this I'll test it out.  (Also why I haven't selected an answer).

Comment: Hey, that's great that it worked for you. Thanks for coming back and accepting it.

Comment: @madreflection I hate open questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Any` methods in your question look like they were intended to be extension methods on a source sequence but they were missing the parameter for the target object.

Conceptually, this is what I believe you were looking to do:

```cs
public static bool Any<TEntity, TProperty>(this IEnumerable<TEntity> source, Func<TEntity, TProperty> selector, TEntity other)
{
    if (source is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (selector is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));
    if (other == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(other));

    TProperty otherProperty = selector(other);

    return source.Any(item => EqualityComparer<TProperty>.Default.Equals(selector(item), otherProperty));
}
```

Now, that'll work on objects in memory, but since you have the [entity-framework-core](/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core) tag, we'll need something that deals with expressions.

To do that, we must first evaluate the property to get the value against which we'll be comparing each entity's selected property.  In memory, we just call `selector(other)` and we're done.  Since we have to deal with an expression now, we need to compile the expression first.  That's fairly simple.

The next step is to build an expression that represents `selector(item) == otherValue`.  Fortunately, we don't need to replace the parameter since we're not trying to fold two separate lambdas into the same expression.  We can simply reuse `selector`'s first parameter.  We then call `Expression.Invoke` with the selector and its parameter, which will be translated into the column reference in the SQL.

Finally, we build the lambda that we can pass along to the built-in `Any` method.

```cs
public static bool Any<TEntity, TProperty>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> selectorExpression, TEntity other)
{
    if (source is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (selectorExpression is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selectorExpression));
    if (other == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(other));

    ParameterExpression itemParameter = selectorExpression.Parameters[0];
    ConstantExpression otherValue = Expression.Constant(selectorExpression.Compile()(other), typeof(TProperty));

    BinaryExpression equalExpression = Expression.Equal(Expression.Invoke(selectorExpression, itemParameter), otherValue);

    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(equalExpression, itemParameter);

    return source.Any(predicate);
}
```

In my own testing, using SQL Profiler to confirm, I was able to get the condition to evaluate in the SQL query.  After changing the property selection expression, the query changed accordingly.

Comment: The second part of this looks right on... I want to test this so bad.

Comment: The second part is what I knew you wanted after all that discussion. The first part is just to ground other readers in a simpler version of the concept before hitting them with the good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how to build `Expression<Func<TModel, bool>>` from `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>` and `TModel` representing equal predicate, it could be done like this:

```
// Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> propertySelector
// TModel model
var parameter = propertySelector.Parameters[0];
var left = propertySelector.Body;
var right = Expression.Invoke(propertySelector, Expression.Constant(model));
var body = Expression.Equal(left, right);
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(body, parameter);
```

The essential parts are the `Expression.Equal` (the expression equivalent of `==` operator) and the expression for invoking the property selector on the passed object instance.

In case the query provider does not support invocation expressions, it could be replaced with

```
var right = propertySelector.Body.ReplaceParameter(
    propertySelector.Parameters[0],
    Expression.Constant(model));
```

where `ReplaceParameter` is the usual `ExpressionVisitor` based helper for replacing `ParameterExpression` with another arbitrary expression (pretty much like `string.Replace`, but with expressions):

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
        => new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            => node == Source ? Target : node;
    }
}
```